# Angular PrimeNG Chart Module: Customize hover text

Tags: angular, chart.js, customization, primeng

In the PrimeNG chart, when I hover over a data point I can see the black box with some information about the point. How can I customize this box? I want to add my own HTML for that hover infobox.

P.S: PrimeNG Chart Module uses chart.js under the hood.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use **External (Custom) Tooltips** as explained [here](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/3.7.1/configuration/tooltip.html#external-custom-tooltips)

> External tooltips allow you to hook into the tooltip rendering process so that you can render the tooltip in your own custom way. Generally this is used to create an `HTML` tooltip instead of an on-canvas tooltip.

Please take a look at this [sample](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/3.7.1/samples/tooltip/html.html) that illustrates how it can be done.